# EventKit What am I doing wrong?

Tags: swift, macos, eventkit

I am trying to access reminders for macOS using EventKit but when I try to access the default calendar it says "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping" although there is a default list set and an account set. This worked for iOS but it is not working on macOS. Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {  
    super.viewDidLoad()  

    eventStore = EKEventStore()    
    eventStore.requestAccess(to: .reminder) { (granted, error) in  
        if granted{  
            allReminders = [EKReminder]()  
            let cal = eventStore.calendars(for: .reminder).first  
            let predicate = eventStore.predicateForIncompleteReminders(withDueDateStarting: nil, ending: nil, calendars: [cal!])  

            eventStore.fetchReminders(matching: predicate, completion: { (reminders: [EKReminder]?) -> Void in  
                allReminders = reminders!  
            })  
        } else {  
        }  
    }
```

Comment: You are force-unwrapping `cal`. It must be `nil`. Don't force-unwrap optionals.

Comment: Assuming that your access has been granted, then the most likely explanation is that there are no calendars on your Mac that support the reminder event type